# What this peony is suffering from?

Tags: diseases, peonies

Does anyone know what this peony is suffering from?

The leaves aren't wilted, they are rigid and rubbery and have twisted themselves into tight, deformed shapes.

The neighbouring peonies appear healthy and in fact the same peony was healthy last year.

I will cut this to the ground, but should I pull up the tuber?

[image: Sick peony]

Comment: Any exposure (accidental or otherwise) to herbicide?

Comment: Could have been a few metres downwind from my using some "organic" bug spray, but the neighbouring peony is very close and completely unscathed.

Comment: Worth mentioning we have a problem with foxes in our garden and there's an unpleasant smell at the moment! Could their urine do this to a plant?

Comment: Not impossible, if a dog fox aimed at it - its rich in nitrogen and could well burn tender foliage, but its rare for this to happen, and you'd think some would have hit the other plant nearby...